# When will a trigger designated as AFTER UPDATE OF DELETED fire?

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle11g

In my project, I see an Oracle trigger like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AAA   **AFTER UPDATE OF DELETED**
   ON table1    REFERENCING NEW AS NEWROW OLD AS OLDROW
   FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (
NEWROW.FUNCT_ID IN
            (451, 454, 455, 457, 458, 459, 460)
      )
```

What does it mean `AFTER UPDATE OF DELETED`? Does it mean after update, after delete or both?

Answer (score 2):

It means "after update of the field `'deleted'`." `deleted` is a fieldname.